# How does a motor produce two different sounds when rotating at two different speeds?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acoustics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, vibrations

How are two different rotational speeds from the same motor associated with two different sound frequencies produced, i.e., the higher the speed the higher the frequency? Why?

All parts of the same motor are vibrating at two different speeds, and emitting the same frequency because the materials are still the same, bolts, nuts, covers, wires, rotor, stator, etc. If the rotor rotates at two different speeds, producing two different linear frequencies or linear vibrations (because of eccentricities, imperfections, in a real world), and the material adjacent to the rotor and the material of the rotor vibrates at different frequencies, then the change in sound frequency is directly related to the change in angular speed by w = 2pi*f?

Comment: Are you asking why a faster spinning motor creates a higher pitched sound?

Comment: Yes. I didn't have the tachometer at the time to measure directly the speed of a particular pulley of the machine (there are several pulleys and shafts and a motor of this prototype), but I have 8 videos of the experiment with same motor speed set. I analyzed the audio using REW V5.20.4, chose 1/1 smoothing, and average all 8. Then I look for the peak in the graph and found the frequency to be 900 Hz (pitch). I am not sure about this method of determining the angular speed of what rotating body (but I assume this to be that of the motor, or is it wrong) of the prototoype.